# How To Keep Customer Context

Tags: php, session, nginx

I am building a site which people will subscribe to and receive a subscriberID and password. They will be able to create their own records in a shared database and each record will be identified by their subscriberID. This subscriberID must therefore be passed with every query to the system.

What is best practice these days for keeping track of the logged in user and their session state? I am using NGINX, PHP and mySQL. Should I simply store the subscriberID in a cookie or is there a better way?

Comment: You can use `$_SESSION`

Comment: Thanks Ayaou. I wasnt aware of that capability in PHP. Currently looking into it but seems like a good option.

Comment: Why the down vote on a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got around to testing this. Sessions seem to be a bugger to get working with NGINX. In the end it seemed that the default session directory did not have enough permissions. I will work out a more permanent solution, but for the moment I am using a dir in the ec2-user home directory. At the top of each page I use the following which is working well after I set the userID session value on login:

`

```
ini_set('session.save_path', realpath('/home/ec2-user/session'));
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
    header("location: http://example.com/login.php?state=expired");
}
```

`